# Route53: how to create a subdomain blog that answers to both blog.my_site.com and www.blog.my_site.com

Tags: subdomain, amazon-route53

Creating a simple CNAME in the same Hosted zone as the main domain is fine for blog.my_site.com, but it's unreachable by **www**.**blog**.my_site.com.

Here is what I did:

1. Created a separate Hosted Zone, overdid the NS and SOA values
   with the ones from the main domain's Hosted Zone.
2. Set a CNAME for
   **www**.**blog**.my_site.com
3. Created an empty s3 bucket that redirects **blog**.my_site.com to **www**.**blog**.my_site.com

So the main reason I am creating a separate Hosted zone is that I want it to be accessible by both:

- www.blog.my_site.com
- blog.my_site.com

It currently doesn't work. 
I suspect it is because I am trying to create a new Hosted Zone with the same NS and SOA values as my main domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For or your use case, there is no reason to create a separate hosted zone.  I would only keep the my_site.com hosted zone.  Within that zone create your records, including your CNAME for  www.blog.my_site.com.  If it's still not working for you, it maybe helpful if you posted the domain in question.

Comment: Technically it's true that www.blog.my_site.com as another CNAME works. It's just that the place where it points only accepted one domain name and no wild cards in the validation so I was trying to set up a redirect from blog.my_site.com to www.blog.my_site.com, that's why I was looking into another zone. But in the end we can live with just blog.my_site.com